# Django "Unknown column 'userdata.password' in 'field list'" >> fix WITHOUT deleting existing table?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a table that is now called "userdata" in an AWS RDS mysql database. In a past migration, the table had a different name, "users". Now, with the new name, I cannot access the data in the table. I get the error >> 1054, "Unknown column 'userdata.password' in 'field list'".

Other Stack Overflow posts suggest dropping the table and starting over to fix the problem.

**Is there a way to fix this problem without dropping the table?**

Here is my user model, in which I specify the table name "userdata":

```
import uuid
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .managers import CustomUserManager


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    is_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    plan_signup_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    ## default inclusions: id, password, last_login, is_superuser, groups, user_permissions

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "userdata"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, the "password" field is omitted from the "userdata" table. This might be due to improper migration of the table from its prior name of "users" or improper migration of a later migration that added the "password" field.

Create a new migration by running the following command in your Django project directory:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty your_django_app --name add_password_field
```

Open newly created migration file and Add the following code

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('your_django_app', 'previous_migration_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='customuser',
            name='password',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password'),
        ),
    ]
```

and **Migrate** again and this should add the missing "password" field to the "userdata" table without deleting any existing data.
you can add any missing field using this method.